# Error SAP MDM java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: /opt/someplace/test.jks KeyStore not available

Tags: java, sap

При установке SSL соединения приложения по SAPMdm API к SAP MDM серверу вываливается эксепшн:

```
ERROR org.forgerock.openidm.provisioner.openicf.impl.OpenICFProvisionerService - OpenICF connector test of SystemIdentifier{ uri=connector/resSapMdm/'} failed!
org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.ConnectionFailedException: java.security.KeyStoreException: /opt/someplace/test.jks not found
    at com.ltd.openicf.sapmdm.SapMdmConnection.initConnection(SapMdmConnection.java:79)
...
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: /opt/someplace/test.jks not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.ltd.openicf.sapmdm.SapMdmConnection.initSecureSocketFactory(SapMdmConnection.java:115)
    at com.ltd.openicf.sapmdm.SapMdmConnection.initConnection(SapMdmConnection.java:67)
    ... 178 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: /opt/someplace/test.jks KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 180 common frames omitted
```

Сыпится на участке:

```
secureSocketFactory = MdmSecureSocketFactory.getSUNImpl(
                config.getKeyStorePath(),
                config.getKeyStorePassword());
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть дело. Информации по данному вопросу крайне мало. Возможно, файл хранилища нужно создавать как-то по-особенному. В данном случае он создавался:

```
keytool -import -alias test -file /opt/someplace/test.crt -keystore /opt/someplace/test.jks -storepass password -trustcacerts -noprompt
```